# Magento 2 collection loop issue

Tags: product, product-collection, magento2.3

```
<?php
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$app->launch();
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$collection = $productFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($value->getData());exit;
}
echo 'Total products:', $collection->getSize(), PHP_EOL;
```

This code output like - Total products:0
When i disable foreach it shows me correct product count.
Foreach not working with collection even product count is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
try {
    require __DIR__ . '/app/bootstrap.php';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    exit(1);
}
$bootstrap = \Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap::create(BP, $_SERVER);
/** @var \Magento\Framework\App\Http $app */
$app = $bootstrap->createApplication('Magento\Framework\App\Http');
$app->launch();
$objectManager = $bootstrap->getObjectManager();
$productFactory = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');
$collection = $productFactory->create()->getCollection();
foreach ($collection as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre/>";print_r($value->getData());
}
echo 'Total products:', $collection->getSize(), PHP_EOL;
```

Note: just remove `exit;`